# React Change Div Style onClick

Tags: reactjs

I have a collection of `div` that I would like to add/remove a style to with an `onClick` event.

[image]

I am able to add the style, but what I need to have is only one div selected at a time. The code below, when I click the `div` it adds it as a selection but when I click another, it adds it as a second selection. What I need to happen is when a div is selected, the previous div is reverted back to "normal".

```
export default function SearchFilterAttributeBadge(props: {attribute: SearchFilterAtttribute, category: string, clickHandler: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => void}) {

const [selectedSize, setSelectedSize] = useState<string>("");

function highlightSelected(id: string) {
    setSelectedSize(id);
}

return (
    <>
        <div className="col">
            <a className={`badge size-badge ${selectedSize === props.attribute.id.toString() ? "selected-size" : ""}`} data-id={props.attribute.id.toString()} data-name={props.category} data-value={props.attribute.name} onClick={(e) => {props.clickHandler(e); highlightSelected(props.attribute.id.toString())}}>{props.attribute.name}</a>
        </div>
    </>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep a badge stage on parent component. Putting a state in each badge component only make you able to control a single badge's style.

You can fix it by putting a state of selected badge in the parent component. Once you click on any badge, update a selected badge's id. You can use the state to update a badge component afterward.

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null)
  return ids.map(id => <Badge selected={id === selectedId} onClick={() => setSelectedId(id)} id={id} />)
}

const Badge = (props) => {
  return <Button onClick={props.onClick} style={props.selected ? selectedStyle : unselectedStyle}>{props.id}</Button>
}
```

If a state has to be shared across multiple components, then put it on higher component.

Answer (score 0):

since i can not see your whole code, lets assume this one and apply the concept to yours ,

make an array of objects, each object contains the value and an index for it

```
const [activeDiv,setActiveDiv]=useState(null)
const divs = [{value:6.5,index:6.5},{value:5.5,index:5.5},{value:4.5,index:4.5}]

return ({divs.map(div=>{
  return (
   <div style={activeDiv===div.index&& {backgroudColor:"blue"}}
    onClick={e=>{setActiveDiv(div.index)}}> {div.value} </div>)
    })})
```

and by this method whenever you click on any method the active class will be toggeled to it and the previous div will be reverted back